# Seekbar 'unhooking' from media player on orientation change

Tags: java, android

I have a `seekbar` in my fragment that I use to show the progress of a `MediaPlayer`track that is playing.  Everything works as expected until I change orientation of the device.  I save my fragment instance and load it back, and all of the other views are repopulated as they should be, and the music keeps right on playing as it should, but the seekbar goes right to the max, as if the track has reached it's max duration.  The runnable that is updating the seekbar based on the mediaplayer's position keeps running after the orientation change as well, and logging the `currentPos` value in the runnable shows that it stays in sync with the `mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` as it should, even after the orientation change...So basically, it continues to feed the correct position to the seekbar; the seekbar just isn't updating after the orientation change.  It makes me wonder if the seekbar instance stays the same after the change.  If it doesn't stay the same instance, I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

The `onCLick` method of my play button calls the following to start the track and hook up the `seekbar` to it:

```
private void startPlayer(String url){

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();

            playerState = PlayerState.PLAYING;
            setButtonsForPlayerState();

            setSeekBarValues();

            mHandler = new Handler();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mMediaPlayer != null ) {
                        int currentPos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Current pos is " + currentPos);

                        seekBar.setProgress(currentPos);
                        if (currentPos<10000){
                            seekBarStartTime.setText("0:0" + currentPos / 1000);
                        }else{
                            seekBarStartTime.setText("0:" + currentPos / 1000);
                        }
                    }
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                    }
                }
            }

                );

            }

    });
}
```

and here is the `setSeekBarValues()` method that is called in the above method:

```
    private void setSeekBarValues() {
        seekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBarFinishTime.setText("0:" + seekBar.getMax()/1000);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
}
```

`seekBarStartTime` and `seekBarFinishTime` are just TextViews that show the current position and end time of the track, respectivily.
Since all of my other views, streaming music, etc. seems to be working as it should on the re-creation of Activity and Fragment, I don't think it's an issue with saving instance state, but if you want me to post that code as well please  let me know.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Where the code you restore the state of the bar? You probably are not calling the setMax

Comment: Orientation changes call `onCreate`. Is it possible that might be causing it?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos - Thank you.  Your comment made me realize that I wasn't restoring the seekbar at all.  I was thinking that saving the fragment instance would take care of it... Still not sure why it doesn't, but I'll do some more reading..