# Android seekbar getting set to 0 on device rotation

Tags: android-seekbar

I have a very similar problem like
[Seekbar 'unhooking' from media player on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012787/seekbar-unhooking-from-media-player-on-orientation-change), I get the correct output onSaveInstanceState and onCreateView of my progress bar.

I have implemented a media player in a fragment, on device rotation the song is is working fine but the seekbar progress is getting set to 0. I have done the following.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //NOTE: When navigating from one fragment to the next
    //      Bundle/savedInstanceState is always null
    //      Implemented it using Shared Preferences.
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(SEEKBAR_PROGRESS, utils.getProgressPercentage(getCurrentPosition(), getDuration()));
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> onSaveInstanceState : " + savedInstanceState.getInt(SEEKBAR_PROGRESS));
}
```

and onCreateView I am checking the savedInstanceState if it is not null and > 0 I am setting the seekbar progress, but it is not working, can someone please tell me why?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        mUri = arguments.getParcelable(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.DETAIL_URI);
    }

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_track_player, container, false);

    currentTimeTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_time);
    totalTimeView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.total_time);
    playButtonView = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.media_play);

    Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(mUri,null, null, null, null);

    mTrackPlayerAdapter = new TrackPlayerAdapter(getActivity(), cur, 0, this);

    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_player);
    mListView.setAdapter(mTrackPlayerAdapter);

    //initialize the play button
    playButtonView = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.media_play);

    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getInt(SEEKBAR_PROGRESS) > 0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> onCreateView savedInstance : " + savedInstanceState.getInt(SEEKBAR_PROGRESS));
        mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(savedInstanceState.getInt(SEEKBAR_PROGRESS));
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

the play song is a runnable thread which is working till the completion even on device rotation.

```
public void playSong(String songUrl, String songTitle) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> Song URL fragment - " + songUrl);
    mSpotifyMusicService.setSongURL(songUrl);
    mSpotifyMusicService.setSongTitle(songTitle);
    mSpotifyMusicService.playSong();

    View v = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_player);
    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.musicSeekBar);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int progress = 0;
                if(startingPoint > 0) {
                    progress = startingPoint;
                }
                while (progress <= 100) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    final long totalDuration = getDuration();

                    progress = utils.getProgressPercentage(getCurrentPosition(), totalDuration);
                    //set the seekbar position, will be used in saved instance later on
                    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();

    //implement the OnSeekBarChangeListener interface methods
    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> User Progress change" + progress);
                mSpotifyMusicService.seek(progress);
            } else {
                updateMediaPlayerControls(
                        utils.milliSecondsToTimer(getCurrentPosition()),
                        utils.milliSecondsToTimer(getDuration())
                );
                //Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> System progress %age - " + progress);
            }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.i("onStartTrackingTouch - ",
                    "" + seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.i("onStopTrackingTouch - ",
                    "" + seekBar.getProgress());
            startingPoint = seekBar.getProgress();
            mSpotifyMusicService.seek(startingPoint);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to have the seekbar outside of the custom adapter and made it part of the fragment, and then used onSaveInstanceState to get the percentage and used it onCreateView after checking if the saved instance bundle is not null.